# How to resolve Chilkat DLL Error - FARM update?

Tags: chilkat

We need your help in resolving this issue faced by one of our end users.
In our application, the Chilkat DLL (ChilkatAx-9.5.0-win32) is used to download/upload the data from the application to/from the SFTP server.  One of the end users who is using our application is unable to upload/download the data from the SFTP server and received an error message.

Could you please let us know the possible cause for this and the resolution for the same.

Here's a screenshot of the error message.
[image]

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall or connection problem.
For solving this issue ask the remote SFTP server administrator for help. He should check SFTP Server log.

[image]